# UIScrollView is nested by UICollectionView. Scrolling doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview

I have a project on swift.

I have a UIViewController in my project with a nested UIScrollView, in which a UICollectionView is nested. The UIScrollView scrolls vertically. The nested UICollectionView scrolls horizontally. The problem is that when trying to scroll vertically behind the UICollectionView, scrolling does not work.
[Scroll in my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0Nv7.jpg)
[This I'm show what's wrong](https://youtu.be/hDVfzTP1dts)

If I set collectionView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false, then scrolling in UIScrollView works as expected correctly and I can scroll vertically even for UICollectionView elements

Comment: did you embed two upper views inside UIScrollView?

Comment: You should check the view hierarchy, you should be able to see what's going wrong from there. It sounds like the scrollView doesn't/can't determine it's content height. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html

Comment: What do you mean by *"trying to scroll vertically behind the UICollectionView"*?

Comment: Vertical scrolling does not work if I start scrolling content from a tap on the UICollectionView. At the same time, the UICollectionView itself, nested in the UIScrollView, will scroll horizontally, as intended.

Comment: I'm show what's wrong https://youtu.be/hDVfzTP1dts

Comment: @ГеоргийЩипин - have you added some type of gesture recognizer to your collection view cell? A quick test, and I'm not having any trouble: https://pastebin.com/95fcxCtP